# Typescript destructure ArrayLike generic type to base type e.g given A find I in: A = ArrayLike<I>

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, typescript-types

I want to achieve the following, which is illegal.

```js
class Test<ArrayLike<I>> {
  arr: ArrayLike<I>;
  current: I
}
```

The following would be another way around this, but I don't know of anything that acts like `ArrayMember`. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
class Test<I> {
  arr: I;
  current: ArrayMember<I>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `infer`

```
type ElementType<T extends ArrayLike<unknown>> = T extends ArrayLike<infer U>? U : never;

class Test<I extends ArrayLike<unknown>> {
  arr!: I;
  current!: ElementType<I>;
}
```

Example:

```
let foo = new Test<string[]>(); 
foo.arr; // type string[]
foo.current; // type string
```

Comment: thank you, I ended up with the following, which I think does the trick `type ArrayMember<T> = T extends ArrayLike<infer U> ? U : never;`